# Why Graph API Explorer doesn't return the wall 'feed' based on a group's id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed, facebook-group

When I test the Graph API Explorer from facebook site and write the following parameters:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/'groupid'/feed?access_token='my access token'
```

it returns

```
{
  "data": 
 [
 ]
}
```

I tried it with several group ids and all return the same result,  while if I try members instead of feed it returns the list of members.

Is there a bug in the feed of a group?
Here is how you can generate the issue:

1. Get an access token: xxxxx
2. Get any Group ID: 123456
3. Make the graph api explorer call to retrieve the group's wall based on the group id

   https://graph.facebook.com/123456/feed?access_token=xxxxxxx

The thing is I first thought the problem was from my code, but when I tried it from **facebook graph api explorer** I found out that its not returning any results.
Please I would really appreciate the help as this is part of my master's project and the due is within two weeks!!

Answer (score 1):

1. Assume group id is 481298561918120, please visit https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=481298561918120%2Ffeed
2. If you see

> {   "data": [   ] }

, you should click the "**Get access token**" button on your right-hand, then click/check "**user_groups**". Finally, click "**Get Access Token**" and process the dialog to grant permission

[image]

After you granted the permission, try to click "**Submit**" button. Now you should able to see the feed.

Conclusion: make sure you have granted **user_groups** permission. You can check the permission on "**Scope**" field at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

[image]

Comment: Yes that worked! thanks a lot, one more thing can you tell me how I can set the accesstoken permission to user_groups from my java code?url = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=xxx&client_secret=xxx&grant_type=client_credentials");
   URLConnection urlConnection;
   urlConnection = url.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in;
    String line = null;
   in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
   while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
   {
    System.out.println(line);
   }

Comment: Your URL is to get the APP access token, not user access token as Graph API explorer generated. More info about app access token please visit https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/. I have no problem request https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=481298561918120%2Ffeed (replace user access token with app access token at the access token field)

Comment: I replaced it with app access token but I'm getting Invalid OAuth access token.

Comment: How about directly use "APP_ID|APP_SECRET" (vertical bar in the middle) form as your app access token?

Comment: I dont think there is a user_groups category anymore as of 2.8 at least.

Answer (score 0):

As of api version 2.8 the following requirements should be met.

- Any valid access token if the group is public (i.e. the group's privacy setting is OPEN)
- If the group is not public:

  - The user_managed_groups permission should be acquired
  - And user should be an admin of the group you are about read.

> ### Here is the catch
>
> To use the user_managed_groups permission you need to submit your app for review.
>
> Login Review: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/what-is-login-review

Otherwise you are left with the response:

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

Group Feed API Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/group